# How to make a page recognize node.js code

Tags: node.js

I´ve tried socket.io to create a tiny chat. But now, I´m tring to do the same thing without any dependencies.

My server side seems to be OK, the problem is to render my html page when the browser doesn´t recognize any node.js code, e.g: "require" statement.

The following exception ir raised: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

I put `<script src="chat2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>` on my page where "chat2.js" is my server implementation.

I´m rendering the page when I type "localhost:8080" on the webbrowser. I have no idea to makes page recognize the server side code written in the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

node.js is a server side language. It's designed to run on the server powered by node. What makes this an interesting case is that the server-side language and the client-side language are both JavaScript. In some cases, the same code used on the server-side can also be used on the client side.

For instance, DOM manipulations are examples of actions that can be performed on the server-side, with a document that hasn't been sent to the client, and they're also examples of manipulations that are mostly done on the client-side.

However, you're trying to run code in the browser that can only run on the server.  If the code contains modules that have dependencies on the server, then running it in the client is just not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jmort253. I though that the same situation as socket.io does could be possible using pure node.js. I´m trying to make a simple chat. I put "net" depedency on the server and I did the same on the client. `var net = require('net'); var client = net.connect(8001, function() {...`. But its not possible.

Comment: Absolutely, the net.connect creates a server listening on port 8001, and that's not really something the client was intended for. I think this is just one of the pain points we all deal with when learning SSJS, differentiating between client and server :)